# How to disable Vuetify styling?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js, disable

I'd like to know how I can disable Vuetify styling. It messed up my whole website.
I just need it for the functionality of v-btn and v-text-field. I do not want to use any of the actual styles for anything.

Thanks.

The main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: if so, read source codes of Vuetyfy `v-btn` then implement your own `v-btn` may be better instead of installing the whole Vuetify.

Comment: please share your `main.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme/#disable-theme) you can disable generation of vuetify stylesheet by configuring your plugin like so:

```js
const vuetify = new Vuetify({
    theme: { 
        disable: true 
    }
})
```